# 時系列のデータフレームの作成

Tags: python, pandas

#### 1点目

時系列のデータフレームについて、一日単位の時系列がわかりますが：

```
pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-31', freq='D')
```

output：

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
               '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', 2022-01-07', '2022-01-08', ...
               '2022-01-29', '2022-01-30', '2022-01-31'],
```

もし時間を "2022-01-01 0:00" のようなフォーマットに転換したいなら、どのように修正すれば良いでしょうか？

#### 2点目

もし毎日は同じ値を入れたい場合にどのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-31', freq='D').strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M'),
  'B': 100,
})

df.info()
print(df)

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 31 entries, 0 to 30
# Data columns (total 2 columns):
#  #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
# ---  ------  --------------  ----- 
#  0   A       31 non-null     object
#  1   B       31 non-null     int64 
# dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
# memory usage: 624.0+ bytes
#
#                  A    B
# 0    2022/1/1 0:00  100
# 1    2022/1/2 0:00  100
# 2    2022/1/3 0:00  100
# 3    2022/1/4 0:00  100
# 4    2022/1/5 0:00  100
# 5    2022/1/6 0:00  100
#              :
#              :
```